# using 2 sets one ingnore and 1 alert to parse a large set in python

Tags: python

I am struggling to get my parsing script to work properly and ignore a set of words.

I am using sets because I dont want the to flag them, theory etc..

UPDATE:

to answer a few questions in the comments;
Next is:

```
next(iterator[, default])
Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next

Examples of alert and ignore are:

```
alert = ['apple', 'bird', 'red', 'blue']
ignore = ['hello', 'foo', 'bar']
```

My script is

```
alert_set = set(alert)
ignore_set = set(ignore)
with open("output\data.csv", 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as data_file:
    reader = csv.reader(data_file)
    for row in reader:
        tweet_set = set(row[2].lower().split())
        if alert_set.intersection(tweet_set):
            print(row[2])
```

this works to alert on the words that I want.

I am trying to have it ignore some words so I am doing

```
for row in reader:
    tweet_set = set(row[2].lower().split())
    if ignore_set.intersection(tweet_set):
        next
    else:
        if alert_set.intersection(tweet_set):
            print(row[2])
```

I have also tried

```
for row in reader:
    tweet_set = set(row[2].lower().split())
    if ignore_set.difference(tweet_set):
        if alert_set.intersection(tweet_set):
            print(row[2])
```

I have also tried

```
for row in reader:
    if any(word in ignore for word in row[2].lower()):
        next()
    else:
        tweet_set = set(row[2].lower().split())
        if alert_set.intersection(tweet_set):
            print(row[2])
```

but its not skipping the words in my ignore list.

Any thoughts or help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `but its not ignoring the words.` ? What is `next` ?

Comment: so I thought next would make it go to the next row in the CSV to parse.  What I want is lets say my ignore word is money I want it to not print the row that has that word in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to solve some my problem for now.  Its not using sets but it will work for now.

```
for row in reader:
    if not any(t in row[2].lower() for t in ignore):
        tweet_set = set(row[2].lower().split())
        if alert_set.intersection(tweet_set):
            print(row[2])
```

so ignore looks like this:

```
ignore = ['foo', 'bar', 'buzz']
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your code, maybe a example may help to the clarification of the problem, also what is `next`? also `alert` and `ignore` I presume that both are list, if not maybe that is the problem, if ignore is a string, when you do `set(ignore)` what you really get is the set of the chars of ignore.

Comment: added answers to your questions in my question hope that helps

Comment: playing a little with the CSV module give me interesting result, if do writerow("bar foo") with the corresponding read I get ['b', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'o'] and if I do writerow(["bar foo"]) I get ['bar foo'], then maybe the problem is with what you get from the reading, but for what you say that looks like if not the problem, can you put a example of the file too? also those next look like do nothing, change them for pass also put some prints before you do the check, that may help you to see the problems

Comment: Thats because you need to use writerows("bar foo") with an S

Comment: doing writerows("bar foo") make that I read 1 char at the time ["b"] and if I do writerows(["bar foo"]) I get the same as with writerow("bar foo")

Comment: Doesn't look like he is writing anything it looks like he is reading it

Comment: yes I know, that is why I ask for a sample of the file because if I build a sample myself so that I read some of the words and use his code I found no problem...

Comment: @Copperfield just posted the answer that I came up with hope that helps

Comment: because a cannot add a comment there, I will do here. This solution looks interesting but I see a problem with it, it will reject anything that has one the ignore words as sub-string, for example with that ignore set this text "that apple was a bargain" will be rejected because the "bar" in "bargain", if that is the intend then fine otherwise try instead doing the `tweet_set` first and then `if not any ( word in ignore for word in tweet_set)`